# Create datatable in angular component

Tags: angular, angular-datatables

I am developing one Angular 2 application. I have one module called Home. This module has one component called with the same name.

HomeModule.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router/';
import { DataTablesModule } from 'angular-datatables';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path : '',
    component : HomeComponent,
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
   CommonModule, 
   RouterModule.forChild(routes),
   DataTablesModule
 ],
 declarations: [HomeComponent]
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

HomeComponent.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'dr-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
 dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dtOptions = {
      data: 
        [
          {
            "id": 860,
            "firstName": "Superman",
            "lastName": "Yoda"
          },
        ],
      columns: 
        [
          {
            title: 'ID',
            data: 'id'
          }, {
            title: 'First name',
            data: 'firstName'
          }, {
            title: 'Last name',
            data: 'lastName'
          }
        ]
    };
  }
}
```

HomeComponent.html:

```
<table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" class="row-border hover"></table>
```

I need to add one button in HomeComponent.html for add dynamically rows in my datatable. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.
David.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build the actual data inside of the table. You can do this with something like...

HomeComponent.html

```
<table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" class="row-border hover">
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let row or dataRows">
      <td>id</td>
      <td>name</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<input [(ngModel)]="input.id"></input>
<input [(ngModel)]="input.name"></input>
<button (click)="saveInput()">save</button>
```

and in HomeComponent.ts

```
public dataRows = [];
public input = {};

saveInput() {
  this.dataRows.push({id: this.input.id, name: this.input.name});
  this.input = {};
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. The example does not work for me. The element is added to the list called dataRows, but the datatable instance does not update.

Comment: Okay then please setup an example plunkr with your specific setup and I'll take a look at how to resolve.

Comment: I think it should be "let row of dataRows" not or

Answer (score 0):

simple using below CMD you can generate the data table

`ng generate  @angular/material:material-table --name=data-table`